# What causes stack overflows to occur? Why do these lines cause stack overflowing and how do I fix it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting stack overflow errors and i'm not sure what a stack overflow error is or how to fi it. I've looked online to try to understand stack overflows but i'm pretty lost. If anyone could explain to me what in my code is causing the overflow that'd be great

Here is my Hero class:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Hero extends DocumentMainNew
    {
        public var health:Number;
        public var mana:Number
        public var vx:Number;
        public var vy:Number;
        public var allowJump:Boolean;
        public var collision:Boolean;

        public function Hero():void
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
        }

        public function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            //Gravitates the player
            vy += 2;

            //Moves the player
            angela.x += vx;
            angela.y += vy;
            //processes collisions 
            processCollisions();
            //scrolls the stage
            scrollStage();
        }
        public function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (e.keyCode)
            {
                case 37: //left arrow
                    vx = -7;
                    break;
                case 39: //right arrow
                    vx = 7;
                    break;
                case 38: //up arrow
                    if(allowJump)
                    {
                        vy = -20;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
        public function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            switch (e.keyCode)
            {
                case 37:
                    vx = 0;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    vx = 0;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    break;
                default: 
            }
        }
        public function processCollisions():void
        {
            //detects when player is falling
            if(vy > 0)
            {
                //respawns the player if they fell of the stage
                if(angela.y > stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    angela.x = _startMarker.x;
                    angela.y = _startMarker.y;
                    _boundaries.x = 0;
                    _boundaries.y = 0;
                    vy = 0;
                }
                //otherwise, processes collisions with boundaries
                while(_boundaries.hitTestPoint(angela.x, angela.y, true))
                {
                    allowJump = true;
                    angela.y -= 0.1
                    vy = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my main document:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip
    import flash.events.Event
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent
    import Hero
    public class DocumentMainNew extends MovieClip
    {
        public var angela:Hero = new Hero;
        public var enemy1:Enemy = new Enemy;
        public var _boundaries:Boundaries;
        var _startMarker:StartMarker; 

        public function DocumentMainNew():void
        {
            _startMarker.visible = false;
            addChild(angela);
            addChild(enemy1);
            angela.health = 100;
            angela.mana = 100;
            stage.focus = stage;
        }

        public function scrollStage():void
        {
            _boundaries.x += (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - angela.x;
            angela.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
            enemy1.x = _boundaries.x + 30;
            _powerup.x = _boundaries.x - 200;

        }
    }
}
```

Heres the error:

Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
at DocumentMainNew()[/Users/s2111908/Desktop/Game/DocumentMainNew.as:9]     at Hero()[/Users/s2111908/Desktop/Game/Hero.as:16]

Line 9 of DocumentMainNew is: public var angela:Hero = new Hero;
Line 16 of Hero is: public function Hero():void

It says at DocumentMainNew() and at Hero() many many times but i didn't want to paste all of it. If the number of times is important let me know and i'll ad a picture. I'm fairly new to AS3 so if anyone has any tips on how to improve my code in anyway please let me know.

Comment: these are two completely separate questions. For the first one did you try google?

Comment: Yes and i don't understand what it's saying. I think I just found the problem though. I changed public class Hero extends DocumentMainNew to ...extends MovieClip. The only issue is that now it can't find angela from DocumentMainNew. I'm not sure what I should google to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**First**. Please learn how to format your code while posting. The whole code block must be indented. There's a **{}** button just for that.

**Second**. Your mistake is **Hero** extending **DocumentMainNew** class. The problem is not extending itself but the fact you call **new Hero** in the **DocumentMainNew** variable declaration area. Lets see, how it goes.

1. Root instance of **DocumentMainNew** is created.
2. Declaring **angela** variable and assigning a **new Hero** to it.
3. An instance of **Hero** is created.
4. **Hero** is extending **DocumentMainNew** so the superclass initializes first.
5. Declaring **angela** variable and assigning a **new Hero** to it.
6. An instance of **Hero** is created.
7. ...and so on.

I don't know why did you inherited the **Hero** class from the **DocumentMainNew** class, but that was a totally wrong move. You should explain what you did try to solve doing so. It should probably be solved in a very different way.

Comment: I'm pretty new to AS3 so i wasn't aware it worked like that. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? And my bad on the formatting. I've been pasting the code as it as typed in actionscript but it comes out weird on here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BradleyG As I said, you need to explain what you did try to achieve, because in order to *fix* it I should understand your goal, while I do not. The simplest obvious step there: don't inherit **Hero** from **DocumentMainNew**. Make it **Hero extends MovieClip**. You also might want to learn the basic OOP concepts: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html

Comment: The Hero class is the player. So the Hero class contains mainly the controls of the player. I want the Hero class to contain all the code that has to do with the player. I am familiar with the concept of OOP just not much in actionscript. I have read a lot of the Adobe info on it but i'm still struggling.

Comment: @BradleyG If you want Hero class to have all core related to player, just put it there, no? I still don't understand the problem, sorry.